# Properties of pairing-reversing automorphisms of integral lattices

Tags: lattices

Let $\Lambda$ be an integral lattice with the symmetric bilinear form (or the pairing) $\langle,\rangle$.

I'd like to know any reference (or even just the standard math terminology) for (the properties of) homomorphisms (as an Abelian group) $\sigma:\Lambda\to\Lambda$ such that

- It reverses the pairing $\langle \sigma a,\sigma b\rangle=-\langle a,b\rangle$
- The homomorphism $\sigma_D$ induced on $D=\Lambda^*/\Lambda$ is an involution, $\sigma_D{}^2=1$.

(I'm not sure if it's really a math-research level question; but it's related to my physics research.)

Comment: The info on this post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58825/non-degenerate-alternating-bilinear-form-on-a-finite-abelian-group almost fixes the structure of $D$ and $\sigma_D$ *if* $\langle a,\sigma_D a\rangle=0$ for $a\in D$; but in my case $\langle a,\sigma_D a\rangle$ can be $1/2 \mod \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The case with $\langle a,\sigma_D a\rangle=1/2$ was covered in CTC Wall, "QUADRATIC FORMS ON FINITE GROUPS, AND RELATED TOPICS
".